# Hudson is for unit testing or integration testing?

Tags: junit, hudson

Might be a basic question but I want to know  does Hudson run Junit test cases or can be used to run integration test cases?

Comment: A simple google of "Hudson Junit" answers this question..

Answer (score 1):

Hudson, or more recently [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), can be used to run whatever you want, whenever you want (e.g. on a schedule, or after each code check-in).

You can run an Ant script, MSBuild file, shell script, batch script, a combination of these things.. anything.

There is built-in support for displaying reports of your JUnit tests, but with [over 400 plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins), you should be able to do what you need to.